# Assign most people their first choice based on a list of preferred choices

Tags: algorithms

Given a list of choices (say 100), each person in a list (say 30) has to choose 5 choices in the order they would like them to be assigned. How would I assign each person a choice making sure as many people as possible got their first choice (or highest preferred choice)?

Each choice can only be assigned once then it is no longer available

[Please note from comment]:

> [I could] randomize the list of users then go through each one and try and assign their first choice, if it is taken go onto their second etc. But I don't think this would give the optimum result and it seems like there should be an algorithm for it, I just don't know what its called / can't find it. [brackets mine: amWhy]

Comment: Please share your thought so far :)

Comment: randomize the list of users then go through each one and try and assign their first choice, if it is taken go onto their second etc.  But I don't think this would give the optimum result and it seems like there should be an algorithm for it, I just don't know what its called / can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate it as a weighted bipartite [maximum matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29). For example, if you have n people and you ask that (1) as few as possible people should have no choice assigned (2) of those who are assigned, as many as possible should have their first choice, then you could give a weight 1+1/2n for each person's first choice and weight 1 for the remaining choices. See the wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) for classic algorithms that solve this. Your idea of iterative updating is also very well known, see [stable marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) and [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).